# Java: how to make text on clipboard get pasted in UI object with Ctrl+V comand?

Tags: java, clipboard

I am working with the Selenium WebDriver in Java – how can I execute a `Ctrl+V` command to paste text already existing on clipboard into edit box?

Answer (score 0):

This is one way of doing it ...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    final JTextField textField = new JTextField(25);
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.add(textField, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    frame.add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("Paste") {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            Action pasteAction = TransferHandler.getPasteAction();
            ActionEvent actionEvent = new ActionEvent(textField, 0, "paste");
            pasteAction.actionPerformed(actionEvent);
        }
    }), BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    frame.setSize(300, 500);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: can you explain the code above? What are these classes `TransferHandler`, `AbstractAction`...

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the java app needs to be signed if it is running as an applet or JNLP. The JRE sandbox does not allow the system.copy paste buffer to be shared with your program. But if you are running a jar file stored on the local file system, this is not an issue.

To access the copy paste buffer you can try the classes in the package 
 java.awt.datatransfer
You can find a usage example here:
 http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=82

Copy and paste is actually quite complex because different applications can allow for transferring different kinds if data. This complexity is handled by DataFlavor. See:

https://blogs.oracle.com/JavaFundamentals/entry/transferring_text_through_the_clipboard